# How do I create a website using HTML?

Tags: html

I have recently learned how to write HTML pages on a standalone computer, with all the references given to the directories in the local drives.

How, then, can I do the following:

1. Create a website, using HTML. I know I'll be able to create its look, but I don't know what should be given as the reference address (URL) if there is a hyper link (like: href).  So how do I get an address that can be used on the Internet?
2. How do I upload this file to the Internet, do I have to upload it onto a server?  If yes, which?
3. If there are multiple pages then how do I create references between?
4. Most importantly if I have to create this site should I use HTML, or something else?

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Comment: What kinds of functionality do you want the site to have?  Do you want a shopping cart, database connectivity, or just a bunch of plain HTML files?

Answer (score 7):

When developing a website you will want to observe the following:

1. You need to regsiter a domain name that you want people to use to access your site. You can do this using any number of online registrars
2. You will have to get a web host...again there are many. They will give you instructions to upload using FTP or otherwise
3. The references between pages on your website will have to use relative addresses. That is /page2.html rather than http://www.myserver.com/page2.html.
4. You have to use HTML to create the front end. Plus CSS and maybe JavaScript. If you need dynamic content like accessing a database etc then you have to learn server side languages like PHP, ASP.NET or JSP.

Comment: thanks for this one now it is a bit clear..
can you me the exact difference between html and javascript and css php...what are they used for respectively...my ideas aren't clear!!

Comment: I like how you talk about relative addresses, but your example is an absolute one :P

Comment: @Jani: Isn't it still a relative URI because it lacks the base URI of the host?

Comment: @Jani I think that absolute addresses must start with the absolute server name or root of the drive etc. Relative addresses on the other hand are given in terms of the location of the current page. So page.html refers to a page that is in the same directory as the current page, and ../page.html is one directory up etc.

Comment: @Shreyas HTML is used to specify the content of a page...text, images, video and so on. CSS is used to specify the look and layout of the content, so font, alignment, colours etc. JavaScript is used to create dynamic elements like drop down menus, pop ups etc.

Comment: vincent sir can i please get your email id.?

Comment: @Vincent and your example begins with a /, making it an absolute path to the server http root.

@Chuck absolute URLs begin with a / similar to *nix absolute paths

Answer (score 4):

To reference pages and resources (images, css, et.c.) you can use either relative paths, virtual paths or absolute paths.

A relative path shows the relation between the items, for example:

```
An image in the same folder: art.gif
An image in a subfolder: images/art.gif
An image in a parent folder: ../art.gif
An image in a parallel subfolder: ../images/art.gif
```

A virtual path starts with "/", so it's relative to the root folder of the site:

```
An image in the root folder: /art.gif
An image in a subfolder: /images/art.gif
```

An absolute path specifies the complete URL to the resource:

```
An image in a subfolder: http://www.mysite.com/images/art.gif
```

To put the pages on the net, you need some kind of hosting. You can start with searching the web for "free hosting" and you will find plenty of sites where you can try this out.

Most free hosting offer a subdomain or subfolder for your site, like `mypage.thewebhost.com` or `www.thewebhost.com/mypage`. If you want your own domain like `www.mypage.com` you need to register it for a fee. Many hosts offer a domain name "for free" when you buy web space, but you will of course end up paying for it in the end as it's included in the fee for the space.

Regardless of how you create the page, it will use HTML in the end. That's what the web is made of. If you use a server side language like ASP.NET or PHP, they still output HTML pages for the browser.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great site if you're just getting started with HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about how to publish your site on the web and then access it.

- Buy a domain, go to any domain hosting site like godaddy.com etc.

  After buying domain the domain hosting company will send you the details of your account/pwd

  With you account pwd you can access their ftp server.

  Put your current html pages on their ftp server (put them in the public folder)

  Access your html pages on the web now.

Also note it will take atleast a few minutes before your domain info gets published on the dns servers, i.e to say it will take a while before you can access your website (usually a few minutes)

Comment: I -and this a purely personal opinion- dispute your use of the phrase 'good domain hosting site' to describe godaddy.com. See: http://www.google.com/search?q=godaddy+complaints for a list of reasons not to use them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try giving relative urls in the href link. For e.g. if you want to link index.html to page1.html in the same folder you don't need to give complete path of the page1.html for the link. You can simply write `<a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>`
   You can learn more about [relative urls from here](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html)
2. You can get a free web hosting account from sites like http://110mb.com , they also provide a free sub-domain and a ftp account.
3. You need HTML to create webpages. There's no other option.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend.  There's tons of help for web site development.  I just recently switiched from HTML to PHP, but I recommend you use HTML until you are fully comfortable with it.